# solr: curl delete command silently fails

Tags: curl, solr

I am trying to delete all data before reindexing.
Here is my command (I am on windows):

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary "{\"delete\":{\"query\":\"*:*\" }}" http://localhost:8983/solr/mycollection/update
```

I get a successful response, but the data is still there afterwards. What could be the problem?

Comment: you need to commit the same. isnt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your curl command is missing the `commit=true`

Please use the below command with commit in it.

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    'http://<host>:<port>/solr/<core>/update?commit=true' \
    -d '{ "delete": {"query":"*:*"} }'
```

If you are using the curl on the windows then it would be like

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary "{\"delete\":{\"query\":\"*:*\" }}" "http://localhost:8983/solr/mycollection/update?commit=true"
```

Below one can be used through browser :

```
http://host:port/solr/collection_name/update?commit=true&stream.body=<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>
```